# Python-2.7 NLTK saving and opening files with data from class type nltk.Text

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am in the process of using NLTK to analyse some very large text files (ie 2GB of plain text) which will hopefully become part of my PhD thesis (not in computer science - I'm not a software engineer).
The workflow for this type of process is to convert from ASCII (str) to tokens (list) to nltk.Text (class).
Because the files are very large and take some time to process, I would like to be able to save the files at various stages of this workflow in order to not have to repeat the processing during subsequent sessions.
Converting and saving the ASCII and tokens is not a problem, and neither is saving the nltk.Text data:

```
def savetextfile(filename, text):
    f=open(filename,'w')
    for a in range(len(text)):
    b=text[a].encode('ascii','ignore')
    f.writelines((b)+'\n')
```

This enters each item in the text object onto a new line. The problem I have is reading back this data. I can instantiate an object of class nltk.Text thus:

```
text=nltk.Text([0],'')
```

but if I then try to construct a loop to put the data back into the object:

```
with codecs.open('testdata.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as filehandle:
    filecontents=filehandle.readlines()
    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = (line[:-1]).encode('ascii','ignore')
        print(current_place) #just for testing
        type(current_place) #just for testing
        text=nltk.Text([a],current_place)
        a += 1
```

what ends up being entered into the text object is the number of lines in the testdata.txt file. As you can see I am addressing this class type as though it is a 1 dimensional array, but it isn't, and the reason I'm guessing is because the documentation is either poor or non-existent (well I can't find it anyway). I would be very grateful for any pointers, thanks.

Comment: Tangentially, now would be an excellent time to abandon Python 2 in favor of the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Why do you write the file as UTF-8 if you force the contents to 7-bit ASCII?

Comment: Both of these comments have a related reason. When I first started this project it was in Python 3 but I ran into problems with the encoding. I understand that Python 3 was supposed to detect the encoding of plain text but in my case it didn't. The option to override the wrongly detected encoding didn't work either. I realise that there are some problems with the code (and I appreciate the feedback), but encoding isn't the problem I'm asking about.

Comment: Indeed, but resolving it might help you actually get there.

Comment: You should really avoid Python3. Also if the text is share-able, it'll be much easier to identify the problem. Trying to shoot in the dark, here but have you tried `io.open('testdata.txt', 'r', encoding='latin-1')` ?